# In psplot some dotsyles are not working

Tags: miktex, pstricks

in psplot the following dotstyles are not working anymore (after miktex installation on new Computer):
dotstyle=x, dotstyle=oplus, dotstyle=otimes

In "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pstricks.tex" these plotstyles are defined (in contrast to the working dotstyles) with

\newpsfontdot...{***StandardSymL***}
- I think there is my Problem.

With the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.0cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.3,-1.3)(5,5)%
\psaxes[labels=all,ticks=all]{->}(0,0)(4,4)%
\psplot[plotstyle=dots,plotpoints=4,dotsize=5pt 5,dotstyle=o]{0}{3}{x 1.33 mul }
\psplot[plotstyle=dots,plotpoints=4,dotsize=5pt 5,dotstyle=x]{0}{3}{x}
\psplot[plotstyle=dots,plotpoints=4,dotsize=5pt 5,dotstyle=oplus]{0}{3}{x 0.75 mul}
\psplot[plotstyle=dots,plotpoints=4,dotsize=5pt 5,dotstyle=otimes]{0}{3}{x 0.5 mul}
\end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

I get this plot:
[image]

Thanks for help, Fritz

Thanks for your response. I see no error in log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6930 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2019.1.18)  14 FEB 2019 10:22
entering extended mode
**./minimal4.tex
(minimal4.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrartcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (article)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrbase.sty"
Package: scrbase 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\tocbasic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
\scr@dte@tocline@numberwidth=\skip41
\scr@dte@tocline@numbox=\box27
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 134.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrartcl)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 211
4.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\scrsize11pt.clo"
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/koma-script\typearea.sty"
Package: typearea 2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (type area)
\ta@bcor=\skip42
\ta@div=\count80
\ta@hblk=\skip43
\ta@vblk=\skip44
\ta@temp=\skip45
\footheight=\skip46
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1706.
)
\c@part=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\scr@dte@part@maxnumwidth=\skip47
\scr@dte@section@maxnumwidth=\skip48
\scr@dte@subsection@maxnumwidth=\skip49
\scr@dte@subsubsection@maxnumwidth=\skip50
\scr@dte@paragraph@maxnumwidth=\skip51
\scr@dte@subparagraph@maxnumwidth=\skip52
\abovecaptionskip=\skip53
\belowcaptionskip=\skip54
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box28
\scr@dte@figure@maxnumwidth=\skip55
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 5439.
\c@figure=\count87
\scr@dte@table@maxnumwidth=\skip56
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 5451.
\c@table=\count88
Class scrartcl Info: Redefining `\numberline' on input line 5615.
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/pstricks\pstricks.sty"
Package: pstricks 2018/12/21 v0.69 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/iftex\iftex.sty"
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, 
and LuaTeX
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/tools\shellesc.sty"
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 69.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty"
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 225.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16
)
\XKV@depth=\count89
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex"
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count90
\pstFP@xia=\count91
\pstFP@xib=\count92
\pstFP@xfa=\count93
\pstFP@xfb=\count94
\pstFP@rega=\count95
\pstFP@regb=\count96
\pstFP@regs=\count97
\pstFP@times=\count98
)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-c
ommon.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks17
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfutil-c
ommon-lists.tex))
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeys.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks18
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks19

(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfi
ltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20
))
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.co
de.tex
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmath.code.t
ex
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathcalc.co
de.tex
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathutil.co
de.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@xa=\dimen106
\pgf@xb=\dimen107
\pgf@xc=\dimen108
\pgf@y=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@yb=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\c@pgf@counta=\count99
\c@pgf@countb=\count100
\c@pgf@countc=\count101
\c@pgf@countd=\count102
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count103
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count104
)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathparser.
code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count105
\pgfmath@box=\box29
\pgfmath@toks=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks23
)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.code.tex
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.random.code.tex)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.base.code.tex)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.round.code.tex)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfunctio
ns.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/math\pgfmathfloat.c
ode.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count106
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen114
\pgffor@skip=\dimen115
\pgffor@stack=\toks24
\pgffor@toks=\toks25
)
\psLoopIndex=\count107

`PSTricks' v2.92  <2018/12/27> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen116
\pst@dimb=\dimen117
\pst@dimc=\dimen118
\pst@dimd=\dimen119
\pst@dimg=\dimen120
\pst@dimh=\dimen121
\pst@dimm=\dimen122
\pst@dimn=\dimen123
\pst@dimo=\dimen124
\pst@dimp=\dimen125
\pst@hbox=\box30
\pst@ibox=\box31
\pst@boxg=\box32
\pst@cnta=\count108
\pst@cntb=\count109
\pst@cntc=\count110
\pst@cntd=\count111
\pst@cntg=\count112
\pst@cnth=\count113
\pst@cntm=\count114
\pst@cntn=\count115
\pst@cnto=\count116
\pst@cntp=\count117
\@zero=\count118
\pst@toks=\toks26
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pstricks.con")
\psunit=\dimen126
\psxunit=\dimen127
\psyunit=\dimen128
\pst@C@@rType=\count119
\pslinewidth=\dimen129
\psk@startLW=\dimen130
\psk@endLW=\dimen131
\pst@customdefs=\toks27
\pslinearc=\dimen132
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen133
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen134
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen135
\everypsbox=\toks28
\psframesep=\dimen136
\pslabelsep=\dimen137
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen138
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen139
\pst@shift=\dimen140
)
File: pstricks.tex 2018/12/27 v2.92 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/pstricks\pst-fp.tex")
File: pst-fp.tex 2018/12/27 v2.92 `PST-fp' (hv)
)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/pst-plot\pst-plot.sty
Package: pst-plot 2011/06/05 v1.00 LaTeX wrapper for `pst-plot' (HV)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/xkeyval\pst-xkey.sty"
Package: pst-xkey 2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/latex/multido\multido.sty
Package: multido 2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)


(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/multido\multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>
\multido@count=\count120
\multidocount=\count121
\multido@stuff=\toks29
)
File: multido.tex 2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
)
Package: pst-plot 2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)

(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-plot\pst-plot.tex
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-tools\pst-tools.tex
`PST-tools' v0.09b, 2017/12/03 (hv))
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pstricks-add\pstricks-a
dd.tex
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-node\pst-node.tex
 v1.41, 2017/12/30
\psrow=\count122
\pscol=\count123
\psmatrixcnt=\count124
\psrowsep=\skip57
\pscolsep=\skip58
\pst@args=\count125
\num@pts=\count126
\pst@argcnt=\count127
)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-arrow\pst-arrow.tex
`pst-arrow' v0.01, 2016/09/01 (dr,hv)
\pshooklength=\dimen141
\pshookwidth=\dimen142
)
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-3d\pst-3d.tex
`PST-3d' v1.11, 2010/02/14 (tvz))
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pst-math\pst-math.tex
`pst-math' v0.64 , (CJ,hv)) `pstricks-add' v3.87, 2019/01/12 (dr,hv)
\psparallelogramsep=\dimen143
\pst@cntC=\count128
\pst@stepcount=\count129
\chart@ColorIndex=\dimen144
\chart@ColorStep=\dimen145
\pst@chartHeight=\dimen146
\pst@chartStackDepth=\dimen147
\pst@chartStackWidth=\dimen148
\chart@Toggle=\count130
\psVectorCtr=\count131
)
 v1.91, 2018/08/31 (tvz,hv)
\pstRadUnit=\dimen149
\pstRadUnitInv=\dimen150
\pst@linecnt=\count132
\RCD@file=\read1
\psxlabelsep=\dimen151
\psylabelsep=\dimen152
\psk@subticksize=\dimen153
\pst@xticksizeA=\dimen154
\pst@xticksizeB=\dimen155
\pst@xticksizeC=\dimen156
\pst@yticksizeA=\dimen157
\pst@yticksizeB=\dimen158
\pst@yticksizeC=\dimen159
\@digitcounter=\count133
\psk@llx=\dimen160
\psk@lly=\dimen161
\psk@urx=\dimen162
\psk@ury=\dimen163
\pst@xunit=\dimen164
\pst@yunit=\dimen165
)
File: pst-plot.tex 2018/08/31 1.91 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
) (minimal4.aux)
\openout1 = `minimal4.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 9.
 [1

] (minimal4.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11388 strings out of 492947
 211672 string characters out of 3135550
 425972 words of memory out of 12000000
 15195 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6379 words of font info for 23 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,7n,55p,9110b,290s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on minimal4.dvi (1 page, 16932 bytes).
```

Comment: Personally I tested your code that works perfectly with dot indicators. In my opinion it would be very useful if you could insert exactly the complete track of the .log file of the errors that are reported after any compilation.

Comment: it looks like a problem with MikTeX and the setting of GhostScript. It does not find the font files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Installation of package 'symbol' the missing fonts are installed in

> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\fonts\type1\urw

I found a hint in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25564/missing-file-from-the-package-symbol)

Now it's working as expected. I expected that missing packages are installed automatically, but don't care. Thanks to all.