# Pstricks stops working after update 18-2-19, problem with pgf?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, miktex-update

I tried to fix my problem with dotsymbols in pstricks (see [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474499/in-psplot-some-dotsyles-are-not-working)) and end up with an update of several packages in miktex. Now (after update) pstricks stops working. I get the following error:

```
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgfkeysfi
ltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks20
))
(C:\Users\flenk1\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex/generic/pgf/utilities\pgffor.co
de.tex
Loading [

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \ProvidesPackageRCS[v
                          \pgfversion] $Header: /cvsroot/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf...

? x
```

I tried the following compile commands:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\latex.exe
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\lualatex.exe
```

but all end up with the same error. Even after a complete reinstallation of miktex the same error remains.

My Minimum example is really minimal:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\end{document}
```

Is there a possibility to switch back to an older version of pstricks or pgf? Most of my files use pstricks, so for me this error is catastrophic.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Update MikTeX in admin *and* user mode. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864. The log shows that `pgf` is installed as a user. If `pstricks` is installed as admin that could explain package incompatibilities. If you are using a multi-user installation and have packages installed both as user and as admin it is crucial to run the updater in both modes to avoid package version mismatches like these. (That is one of the reasons why people usually recommend single-user installs: You don't have that issue there.)

Comment: @moewe This seems to solve the problem. Do you want to write an answer, or do you have another idea of what to do with this question?

Comment: @marmot Structurally this should be a problem related to the recent https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/469005/35864 and friends. We could close this as a  duplicate.

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks a lot to @moewe